# how to recompile the 3rd party jars using lower version

Tags: java, eclipse, jxl

I am stuck with an issue because of lower version of java.
I am using eclipse, I set the compiler level to 1.5 version and using jars like

1. ojdbc.jar
2. jxl.jar

But its throwing the following error. So I am suspecting that the jars were compiled with higher version so may be thats the reason for this error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Please someone let me know how to recompile 3rd party jars with lower version. Or any other solution or my issue.

Comment: You have to download the source code and recompile for the version you need.

Comment: i found a version which was compiled on 1.4 thanks.

Comment: Java 5 has been out of (regular) support since 2009, you might want to consider upgrading

Comment: yes but thats the existing java on the VM. Its clients decision. else I would have used java 7 or 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jxl.jar was the culprit. may be the latest version was compiled on 1.7 
+ version

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.9%20%28Java%201.4%29

I download this jar which was compiled with 1.4 version of java. so it will be safe on 1.5 version :) :)